# Details to run the app for mobile version using Rocket.Chat.Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, mobile, rocket.chat

Could you detail a bit more here please:
https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Cordova/blob/develop/README.md#attention

I'd like my users to be able to use the mobile app.
I tried (hard) to understand, but I failed :)

I am using meteor galaxy and mLab.

I also want to understand the terms used here?

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Cordova#create-conf-files

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The conf files for using Bugsnag and Android push notification

- Bugsnag.apiKey
  This is for using Bugsnage. You can skip this setting
- ANDROID_SENDER_ID
  If you want to implement any push notification, you must set this.
  This is google project's number.

Answer (score -2):

For making app, you can use "Cordova Build".

It is building a debug app.
If you want to make a release app, please use `--release` flag.

Comment: In which way is this answering the question?